# Cordova FileTransfer sends file but nothing received

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, file-transfer, phonegap

I'm sending a video recorded via Cordova's [MediaCapture plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html) to a remote server via the [FileTransfer plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html), but nothing - neither the file, nor any data whatsoever - is arriving at the server end. The server receives the request, but it seems to be empty.

According to Cordova, everything goes fine. Here's the readout from the success callback:

[image]

And here's my JS: (`mediaFiles[0]` is the captured video file)

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileName = 'foo.bar';
options.mimeType = mediaFiles[0].type;
options.params = {
    mime: mediaFiles[0].type
};

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(
    mediaFiles[0].fullPath,
    encodeURI("http://xxxxxx.com/receive-video.php"),
    function (r) {
        console.log(r);
        alert('sent file!');
    },
    function (error) {
        alert('error');
        console.log(error);
    },
    options,
    true
);
```

(Note the last param, [`trustAllHosts`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html#upload), is set to true since my test server is self-signed.)

Cordova clearly thinks it's sent data, but my PHP script disagrees. Here's my PHP:

```
file_put_contents(
    'readout.txt',
    "Payload\n----------\n".
    file_get_contents('php://input').
    "\n\nRequest\n----------\n".
    print_r($_REQUEST, 1).
    "\n\nFiles\n----------\n".
    print_r($_FILES, 1).
    "\n\nPost\n----------\n".
    print_r($_POST, 1)
);
```

As you can see, I'm looking pretty much everywhere. All these result in empty readouts, however, in `readout.txt`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out the [`chunkedMode` param](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html#upload) (in `options`) was the culprit.

In case this helps anyone else, disable this (it's true by default) and all should be fine.

```
options.chunkedMode = false;
```

Not sure how to explain the behaviour of the empty request with it turned on, though. The param exists to send the file in chunks, to allow for progress feedback of some sort.

Comment: You saved my day. I was trying different things for over 2 hours and then hit upon this solution. It works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped someone.

Comment: Sadly a few years later this doesn't solve the exact same issue im having. :(

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 I don't think it's about years; the above commenter (Rajesh) said it was the solution for him only last week :)

Comment: @Mitya You're right, I didn't notice that.  Either way I'm using Ionic, which has a different method than cordova alone.  `chunkedMode` is deprecated now but Ionic is still insisting on using an outdated plugin.  I can't seem to find a solution to this problem for me even after modifying my php.ini.  How did you end up finding this solution?  maybe it will put me on the right path to finding mine.

Comment: My solution was what I outlined above - disabling chunked mode. If that doesn't fix it for you, then, given I don't know Ionic and how that may be affecting things, I probably can't help much. Check the size of the request doesn't contravene your php.ini settings (it sounds like you've done that) and perhaps ask your host if they can see why the request is arriving empty.